# Column name or number value not match error from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure code. When I run this code with all needed parameters, I get an error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Anyone can give me a hint about what's wrong with this SQL?

Note: I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

```
USE [TestDataBase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductsByKeyword] 
    @Keyword NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @MinPrice FLOAT = NULL,
    @MaxPrice FLOAT = NULL,
    @MaxNumberOfSales FLOAT = NULL,
    @MinNumberOfSales FLOAT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ItemsTable TABLE (title NVARCHAR(255))

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Query='select top 500 * from Products where ID in (SELECT TOP 10000 CAST(KEY_TBL.[KEY] AS BIGINT) FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Products, Title, '+char(39)+@Keyword++char(39)+') AS KEY_TBL ORDER BY RANK DESC)'

    PRINT @Query

    INSERT INTO @ItemsTable 
        EXEC sp_Executesql @Query


    SELECT * FROM @ItemsTable           

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Comment: It seems you are selecting more column by select * from.... rather than selecting title only from your dynamic query.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here? It has made this vulnerable to sql injection for no reason at all. As for the error...it can't be more clear. You are trying to insert select * from Products into a table with a single column. And using TOP with no order by mean you can't ensure which rows will get returned.

Comment: `SELECT * ` is a bad enough habit.   `INSERT INTO ` without supplying a column list is even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your "select top 500 *…" query is returning more columns than your table variable can handle.  Either change the * to be one column or change the table variable definition to cover the output of the query